# MVC Index Action Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

im trying to learn MVC and struggling to pass data from a url to a controller. im getting a 404 not found error when i go to localhost:XXX/post/2 - im missign something obvious here. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Conference.Models;

namespace Conference.Controllers
{
public class PostController : Controller
{
    private ConferenceContext db = new ConferenceContext();

    //
    // GET: /Post/

    public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
    {            
        var postList = db.Posts.Where(i => i.PostedToID == id);
        return View(postList.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: If you use localhost:XXX/post/Index/2  does it work?

Comment: Are you using IIS or dev server? (just to verify, "xxx" as app root means you are using IIS...)

Answer (score 1):

Your URL have to be Post/Index/2.

Another possibility is using routing (add this to your RouteConfig.cs):

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Post",
    "Post/{id}/",
    new { controller = "Post", action = "Index", id = ""});
```

Answer (score 1):

default routing (App_start/RouteConfig.cs) is

Controller/Action/id where id is optional in the routing

Your url should be 
**http:// .../Post/Index/2**

The View name should be Index and in the folder

```
Views/Post
```

or

```
Views/Shared
```